# How would I be able to copy a site's data-sitekey with python 3 selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

This is the code that I am trying to pull:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"data-callback="successCallback" data-sitekey="6Lc9qjcUAAAAADTnJq5kJMjN9aD1lxpRLMnCS2TR" data-theme="light" data-size="normal">
```

The data that I need comes after data-sitekey and is this value:

```
6Lc9qjcUAAAAADTnJq5kJMjN9aD1lxpRLMnCS2TR
```

I know the code needs to start off like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='g-recaptcha']")
```

However I do not know how to pull the sitekey specifically past this step.

Comment: .get_attribute('date-sitekey') would get the value for it.

Comment: Answer it so I can give you credit, sir, thank you.

Comment: Actually that did not work.

Comment: sorry data-sitekey I misspelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [get_attribute](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) function.

In your example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='g-recaptcha']").get_attribute("data-sitekey")
```